# Running python script in IBM Watson node.js chatbot

Tags: python, node.js, ibm-cloud, watson, watson-conversation

I made a chatbot in Node.js with IBM Watson. I'm trying to run a python script in it but I'm not able to. I tried browserify and bundled up all dependencies in a .js file and called the script in the html page but still it isn't working.

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    args: 765
};

    PythonShell.run('pyt.py', options, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('results: %j', results[0].toString());
    });
```

It's running on locally between a node.js and a python file. But, doesn't work when I deploy the chatbot on a server.

Comment: Can you share your Python script to verify if it returns something? The Python script it's really running on your server?

Comment: Nope. Nothing happens. The response that I'm trying to get from python isn't getting displayed in Node.js.

Comment: The issue is with the require() in Node.js. None of them seem to work here.

Comment: can you share the error that your terminal shows to you?

Comment: There is no error. I just don’t see the output that I should with the require() running

Comment: try to use console.log(err) and could you please share your pyt.py code? here works okay, but I'm just showing some string on my python code.

Comment: This code works absolutely fine if you run it on the local machine. Issue comes up when you run it on the server(even localhost), the require() doesn't work. I tried browserify, still can't get it to work.

Comment: And there is no response on console on running on the server.

Comment: and on your server the Python is already installed? And on your server when you run just the pyt.py works as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the data returned from the Python script, you should use in your python script, try to put it:

```
print(dataToSendBack)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

And then Node can check your data with:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var pythonProcess = spawn('python',["path/to/script.py", arg1, arg2, ...]);

pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data){
// Do something with the data returned from python script
});
```

- Check more about [`child-process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Comment: I think the issue has more to do with running require() method in Node.js on the localhost server. I'm not able to run any other require methods as well